# How does Argon2id store salts in PHP?

Tags: php, hash, passwords, salt

The PHP implementation of Argon2id generates a salt for the developer. How does the application keep track of this salt? As a developer, how do I account for backups and otherwise ensuring that I don't lose the salt?

Comment: Welcome to crypto.stackexchange - Programming questions are off-topic here, even if they are about cryptography (you'll have noticed that there was no `php` tag). I am migrating your question to stackoverflow.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Luis said, the salt is stored in the result of the hash functions, separated by `$`:

```
password_hash('secret', PASSWORD_ARGON2I);
```

Will return something like this:

```
$argon2i$v=19$m=1024,t=2,p=2$MEhSZkJLQXUxRzljNE5hMw$33pvelMsxqOn/1VV2pnjmKJUECBhilzOZ2+Gq/FxCP4
```

Where:

- `argon2i` is the algorithm
- `v=19` is the version
- `m=1024,t=2,p=2` is the memory, iterations and parallelism options
- `MEhSZkJLQXUxRzljNE5hMw` is the salt
- And `33pvelMsxqOn/1VV2pnjmKJUECBhilzOZ2+Gq/FxCP4` is the actual hash.

So you just have to save the entire string, and it will keep everything PHP needs for its hashing methods, like `password_verify`.

Comment: The PHP docs mentioned none of this - is there a go to resource for more verbose explanations? I'm relatively new to PHP development.

Comment: Small typo, it is `password_verify()` instead of `hash_verify()`.

Answer (score 3):

Even though [the documentation for the `password_hash()` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) labels the function return value the "hash," it is actually a compound string that also incorporates the salt and some metadata to identify which algorithm was used.  The companion [`password_verify()` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) parses this information to do the right thing.

So you just have to store the result of `password_hash()`.